# What are some decent books for explaining the positional ideas of the 4...Nxd5 line of the QGD from black's perspective?

Tags: opening, queens-gambit-declined

Specifically, this line.

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "8"]

1.d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. cxd5 Nxd5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is the subject of Chapter 3 of Alexei Kornev's book [Play 1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6!](https://chess.co.uk/products/play-1-d4-d5-2-c4-e6-alexei-kornev), published by Chess Stars. The contents page of the book is available at the link. It's a repertoire book from Black's perspective. Kornev writes that after 5.e4 "Black must find several very precise moves in order to reach equality".

Answer (score 0):

Since White gets a significant advantage at once with with 5.e4, I doubt that anyone has ever written a book about it.

Comment: But isn't this kind of similar to the Semi-Tarrasch, which someone has probably written a book about?

Comment: Worth mentioning that some top players do play it occasionally, especially at rapid time controls. Kramnik has a dozen or so games as black. Way less bad than 1.d4 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. cxd5 Nxd5 for example. Stockfish gives it +0.3 or so.

Comment: Indeed it has been played, but without much success. Lichess gives the WDL percentages as 37-47-16. Books have certainly been written about openings that may be worse, like 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 f5, but those are tricky and interesting. If I were an author I would not find this an exciting project.

Comment: I think those percentages are for the 4...exd5 variation.

Comment: Interesting to see the line appearing in today's World Cup classical game between the Muzychuk sisters: https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/fide-womens-world-cup-2023/4/2/1

Comment: @James Martin. Thanks for noticing that. The first 10 moves were very normal, leaving white with a nice center and a space advadvantage, about +0.3. Black has exhanged off two minors, castled into safety, and will react to whatever White tries to do.  11.h4 seems like a very creative novelty (although Stockfish is not all that impressed at +0.2) and the game gets very interesting. 

But there is not going to be a book about this for the OP until the line gets more high-level exposure. If certain White tries become popular, then material for a book will start to emerge.